# LINQ: How do I find all the objects whose Array property contains a particular value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I've been searching for a while and could not find exactly what I need.

This questioning might be devoted, since, I suspect there are some alike questions here already. But I think I have a specific case.

I have an object User that contains the property as Array of permissions.

I'm looking for the correct way to grab all the users with a particular permission.

I tried the following:

```
List<User> users = UserRepository.GetUser().Where(u => u.Permissions[0].Equals("MyPermission")).ToList();
```

When doing this, I'm getting an error:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Using .Any() is a safe way

```
List<User> users = UserRepository.GetUser()
    .Where(u => u.Permissions.Any(x => x.Equals("MyPermission"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You get an exception because you blindly index `Permissions` with `[0]`, without checking that it has *any* values at all.

Adding a check for length would fix this problem, but it wouldn't catch `"MyPermision"` outside the initial position.

You can fix this by using `Contains(...)`:

```
// Construct a MyService.UserPermissions object for searching
var targetPermission = new MyService.UserPermissions("MyPermission");
var users = UserRepository
    .GetUser()
    .Where(u => u.Permissions.Contains(targetPermission))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit:** Since it turns out that you are looking for a permission with a specific `PermissionName`, you cannot use `Contains`. You need to use `Any` instead:

```
var users = UserRepository
    .GetUser()
    .Where(u => u.Permissions.Any(p => p.PermissionName == "MyPermission"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm trying to do as you suggested, but I'm getting an error saying "UserPermissions[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains'"

Comment: @gene Is `UserPermissions` a list or an array?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it's an array but it doesn't really matter as `Contains` is also an extension method so arrays have it aswell when `using System.Linq;` is used.

Comment: It is an Array: `public MyService.UserPermissions[] Permissions`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not missing `using System.Linq;` I already have `Linq` used in the same method

Comment: @gene I see what's going on - you are comparing `MyService.UserPermissions` to `string` objects, which cannot be done with `Contains`. Please see the edit for a fix.

Comment: `UserPermissions` class does not have a constructor that accepts parameters

Comment: @gene That's just an example to show that you need a `UserPermissions` object for comparison. Use whatever way you have to construct `UserPermissions` object - a factory, an EOC container, etc. Your comparison method with `"MyPermissions"` string would yield `false` for all permissions, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you for your help. I found the right solution: `List<string> userEmails = UserRepository.GetUser().Where(u => u.Permissions.Any(p => p.PermissionName.Equals("MyPermission"))).Select(e => e.Email).ToList();`  After all, someone has changed the stored procedure and no data was being populated.

Comment: @gene Now that you specified that you are searching for a permission with a specific name, rather than searching for a specific permission object, the answer needed an edit. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of null propagation to skip the users without a permission object and check the array length to avoid out of bounds exceptions:

```
List<User> users = UserRepository.GetUser().Where(u => u.Permissions?.Length > 0 && u.Permission[0] == "MyPermission").ToList();
```

Comment: If Permissions is not null it still might not have an item at index 0, which is where the IndexOutOfBounds error comes from.

Comment: You can always do ?[0]?

Comment: @Postlagerkarte that would still throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` if `Permissions` is not null and there are no elements in the array. Also, as a matter of fact your code doesn't compile, as when `Permissions` is null then `null` will be returned and `null` doesn't evaluate to a `bool` which is what the `Where` clause expects.

Comment: Indeed you have to change the equals to == to make it compile.

Comment: @Postlagerkarte I think you're misunderstanding the question here. the OP is not concerned about `NullReferenceException` thus you need not provide a solution about it rather the OP is concerned about `IndexOutOfRangeException`. have a look at the other answers and you'll see what the OP wants.

Comment: @Aominè I thought the OP was having a null reference exception - thank you for pointing that out - i updated my answer accordingly.